# google adwords api + getting all keywords

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm using the google adwords api, I can retrieve all campaigns, group ads, ads,
but I have no idea on how to retrieve keywords related to an "group ads".
In the google adwords interface, when we select a group ads, we have two tabs, one for ads related to that group ads, and the second for keywords.
but programatily, right now I can only retrieve ads.
I'm using PHP, if some one knew how to do that in php or others programming languages or even a soap call.

Answer (score 6):

To get the details of all the keywords of an adgroup you need the following to get the details of all the keywords.

```
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/init.php';

// Enter parameters required by the code example.
$adGroupId = 'Enter your adgroup id';

/**
 * Runs the example.
 * @param AdWordsUser $user the user to run the example with
 * @param string $adGroupId the id of the parent ad group
 */
function GetKeywordsExample(AdWordsUser $user, $adGroupId) {
  // Get the service, which loads the required classes.
  $adGroupCriterionService =
      $user->GetService('AdGroupCriterionService', ADWORDS_VERSION);

  // Create selector.
  $selector = new Selector();
  $selector->fields = array('KeywordText', 'KeywordMatchType', 'Id');
  $selector->ordering[] = new OrderBy('KeywordText', 'ASCENDING');

  // Create predicates.
  $selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('AdGroupId', 'IN', array($adGroupId));
  $selector->predicates[] =
      new Predicate('CriteriaType', 'IN', array('KEYWORD'));

  // Create paging controls.
  $selector->paging = new Paging(0, AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);

  do {
    // Make the get request.
    $page = $adGroupCriterionService->get($selector);

    // Display results.
    if (isset($page->entries)) {
      foreach ($page->entries as $adGroupCriterion) {
      printf("Keyword with text '%s', match type '%s', and ID '%s' was "
          . "found.\n", $adGroupCriterion->criterion->text,
          $adGroupCriterion->criterion->matchType,
          $adGroupCriterion->criterion->id);
      }
    } else {
      print "No keywords were found.\n";
    }

    // Advance the paging index.
    $selector->paging->startIndex += AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE;
  } while ($page->totalNumEntries > $selector->paging->startIndex);
}

// Don't run the example if the file is being included.
if (__FILE__ != realpath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
  return;
}

try {
  // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
  // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.
  $user = new AdWordsUser();

  // Log every SOAP XML request and response.
  $user->LogAll();

  // Run the example.
  GetKeywordsExample($user, $adGroupId);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  printf("An error has occurred: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain how this is used?

Answer (score 4):

In the Adwords API Keywords are dubbed as AdGroup Criteria. You can add or retrieve the keywords for a certain AdGroup by using the [AdGroupCriterionService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/AdGroupCriterionService.Keyword.html).

If you're using the PHP client library of the Adwords API check out `GetAllAdGroupCriteria.php` in the example files. (don't forget to enter the AdGroupId you want to get the keywords for first)